# Read http body and put it into variables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

how do you create a class to read the html body and phase it into a variable?

Example
the page http://domain.com/page1.aspx

display the following plaintext within the html body content

```
item1=xyz&item2=abc&item3=jkl
```

how do you read content of the html body and assign them to a variables

in this case

variable1=xyz (value taken from item1=)

variable2=abc (value taken from item2=)

variable3=jkl (value taken from item3=)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **two** step process.

**First** you need to get body contents.

**Second** you need to parse content and assign to variables.

Getting body content code look like this:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"((?:.(?!<body[^>]*>))+.<body[^>]*>)|(</body\>.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string InputText = content;

string[] MatchList = exp.Split(InputText);
string body = MatchList[2];
```

Parsing code looks like:

```
        string body = content;
        string [] param = {"&"};
        string[] anotherParam = { "=" };
        string[] str = body.Split(param , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        System.Collections.Hashtable table = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        foreach (string item in table)
        {
            string[] arr = item.ToString().Split(anotherParam, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if(arr.length != 2)
                 continue;
            if(!table.Contains(arr[0])){
                table.Add(arr[0], arr[1]);
            }                
        }
```

Comment: @Adeel: no you didn't! Your code is now equivalent to not having the try/catch block at . So, get rid of the try/catch block. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think you need a try/catch block at all?

Comment: @john actually first i added catch with empty blocks, and then rethrowed after your comment, In case of repitition of query string parameters, the Add method will throw exception if it found the same query string parameter again.For Example if the content of body is x1=1&x2=2&x1=9 . Than the Add method of hastable can throw exceptions(due to duplicate key). so in current situation i am rethrowing.

Comment: @Adeel In asp.net, if you submit one paramter twice, it will be merged in only one. Eg. x1=1,2&x2=2. It is better to check whether the collection already contains a parameter than to let exception happen.

Comment: @Adeel: what if the exception being thrown was because of some other problem? You'd be hiding that other problem. If you're concerned about duplicate keys, then check before adding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean query string but not html body. In that case you can use ASP.NET Page class's property Context as follows

```
string var1 = Context.Request.QueryString["item1"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean actually mean the html body, rather than the query string http//domain.com/page1.aspx?item1=xyz&item2=abc&item3=jkl

Comment: Sorry, i see now... I thought like that because item1=xyz&item2=abc&item3=jkl looks like query string. =)